# Mounting samba share authenticated by kerberos automatically through /etc/fstab

Tags: samba, kerberos

I have a samba server working and I can access the different shares with the command

```
smbclient -k //$server.$my_domain.$net/$my_share
```

I would like the mount to be automatically provided at boot time. The authentication process relies on kerberos. I have tried the following on my /etc/fstab file:

```
//$server.$my_domain.$net/$my_share /mnt/samba cifs sec=krb5i,rw,user 0 0
```

Once authenticated against the kerberos server, I execute mount -a. The commands returns $?==0; but the share is not mounted and nothing on logs files. No clue on logs, on client as on server side.

I think I just don't use the appropriate options in the fstab file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerberos uses the concept of a [**User Principal Name**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Principal_Name) to authenticate itself; this has the form of `user@domain` or `domain\user`.

Since automounts on boot are executed as root, you're probably not providing the right UPN.

You'll have to provide [**the appropriate mount.cifs options**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs):

> ***cruid=arg***
>   sets the uid of the owner of the credentials cache. This is primarily
>   useful with sec=krb5. The default is the real uid of the process
>   performing the mount. Setting this parameter directs the upcall to
>   look for a credentials cache owned by that user.

Also, enable kerberos debug logging on the client and/or server to see if you get the right token.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
I hence have added this option to my /etc/fstab line, without any more results
//$server.$my_domain.$net/$my_share /mnt/samba cifs sec=krb5i,cruid=$user,rw 0 0 :/